# Is NOC required for Visiting family and friends to get a visa in Sweden?

Tags: paperwork, schengen-visas, applications, vfs-global, proof-of-employment

I will be travelling to Sweden to meet my wife. So, I'll need a Visiting visa for Schengen countries. So, my question is: is a NOC (No Objection Confirmation) letter required from my current employer? It is mentioned on the vfs website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Article 14 of the Visa Code https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32009R0810&from=EN covers Supporting Documents and states that the applicant should present “(d) information enabling an assessment of the applicant’s intention to leave the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the visa applied for.”

Within Annex II (Non exhaustive list of supporting documents) of the Code, “proof of employment” is listed as one of the documents allowing for the above assessment to be made. There is no mention of a NOC however VFS practice seems to extend proof of employment to include confirmation of approval of holidays https://www.vfsglobal.se/india/pdf/Sweden-Check-List-For-Tourist-Visa.pdf

Comment: It's worth clarifying that VFS has no say in _deciding_ visa applications, and their "practice" doesn't matter for how the actual consular employees judge the offered evidence.

Comment: @Henning Makholm Agreed. I only recall questions on NOC coming from Indian citizens, which makes me wonder if there is some local custom driving the ‘requirement’.