# What type of visa for a job interview in Germany, and are these documents enough?

Tags: visas, germany, schengen-visas, proof-of-ties

This question involves two parts where in the first I am looking for the correct visa category, and in the second I have ab inquiry on required documents.

I have been invited for a job interview (for a well known software company) in Germany. I am living and working in Turkey. I need to apply for a Schengen visa. After a thorough research, I have found that Germany offers these type of visas:

- Business (I assume this is for business visits that my current company is sponsoring)
- Touristic
- Visitor (I assume this is for visiting a friend or family)

Which of these categories does my need fall in? (For Ireland, there is a specific other category just for job interviews of highly skilled jobs, this might be the case for Germany)

I have completed the application form and I saw that Germany asks for the following:

- My paycheck ( I have this)
- My employment record ( I have this)
- Bank records and sufficient money for covering the travel( I have a letter from inviting company, and also money in the bank)
- Flight and hotel ( I have this)
- Document from my company specifying that I have a leave for the time period of the travel ( I do not have this, my company is heavily bureaucratic, this document would be prepared in two weeks and I do not have this much time)

So, without having the last item would Germany consider my visa positively? I believe they ask this for proving my intention to return home, so do the other documents prove it?

Comment: Are you applying via VFS? There is some anecdotal evidence on TSE that providing a NOC is a requirement set by VFS eg https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/144634/is-noc-required-for-visiting-family-and-friends-to-get-a-visa-in-sweden

Comment: Not VFS, another company called idata. Here is the required documents. https://www.idata.com.tr/de/en/p/required-documents-de#//